# Целесообразность использования Java в написании backend-а

Tags: java, node.js, сервер, веб-сервер

Не думаю, что использование сервлетов и tomcat является популярным способом написания бэкенда для сервисов. Так вот, чтобы вопрос не был слишком общим, спрошу: 
с помощью каких средств (и почему) бэкенд писать лучше всего (конкретно в плане производительности, легкости, скорости работы, удобства для работы фронтендеров) и по каким критериям Java-способ написания бэкенда плох и почему? 
Например, node.js является одним из самых популярных средств для бэкенда, чем конкретно Java хуже для использования в тех же целях?

Comment: Д ничем. Что еще за 'хуже', 'лучше'? Вообще, ЯП не важен, просто мне, например, удобнее писать на Java, так как я пишу под андроид. Кому-то проще на этом node.js и т.д

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что человек хочет не разобраться, что лучше, Java или что то еще,а просто накинуть на вентилятор. Отсюда и постановка вопроса "Чем Java хуже?".
Что касается node.js - у меня опыт с ним небольшой, но насколько я помню, его производительность, по сравнению с Java оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: ЯП всего лишь инструменты, а вот уже ваши знания и умение с ними обращаться и составляют определение целесообразности.

Comment: @МаксимГурин встал вопрос о работе над проектом, я считал, что средства Java-ы гораздо менее удобны для этих целей и не очень для этого приспособлены. Если я пишу на Java, то это не значит, что можно все под одну гребенку подметать и писать все на одном языке, просто потому что ты это можешь и потому что ты уже умеешь писать на нем. И ваши ощущения уберите подальше и оставьте при себе - в вопросе спрашивается именно то, что там написано, черным по белому.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Главное преимущество и проклятие скриптовых языков - их динамическая природа. С одной стороны это даёт быстрый цикл разработки, а с другой утяжеляет поддержку крупных проектов. В строготипизорванной Java большая часть ошибок, особенно глупых, уходит на этапе компиляции. С другой стороны, чтобы запустить простой проект на Java придётся выполнить много лишних телодвижений. Ну и всем известная смешная картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Поэтому критерии лучше/хуже надо рассматривать в контексте особенностей конкретного проекта и выбирать инструмент под задачу, не забивать кувалдой шпильки и не стучать ювелирным молоточком по железнодорожному костылю.

Comment: Вот именно из-за таких моментов, которые отображает эта картинка, я и решил задать вопрос :) Ещё меня смущает удобство взаимодействия бэкенда и фронтедеров. Не так много людей, которые пишут фронтенд, вообще знакомы с С-подобными языками, максимум с js, и вряд ли по этой причине все будет суперудобно.

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не знаю картинок отражающих другую сторону медали, способных вместить в себя всю боль многолетней поддержки крупного нагруженного проекта на динамическом языке.

Comment: С какой стати фронтендер вообще должен знать на чём написан бэкенд? На этапе проектирования оговаривается протокол обмена данных между бэком и фронтом и всё, неважно какие именно языки будут этому протоколу следовать.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от размера приложения и планируемого срока жизни проекта. Чем больше приложение и больше планируемый срок его существования, тем больше плюсов получит Java. И наоборот - на маленьких проектах, и на краткосрочных проектах скорее всего Node.js будет предпочтительнее.